# Настройка nginx для отдачи картинок

Tags: nginx

Изображения хранятся по пути site.ru/upload/catalog/search/img.png
но в БД путь к изображению прописан как site.ru/upload/catalog/search_img.png
В консоли браузера получаю ошибку: 
GET http://site.ru/upload/catalog/search_img.png 404 (Not Found)

Полагаю, тут надо прописать rewrite в конфиге nginx при отдаче изображений и заменить search_ на search/.

Или как-то иначе можно решить данную проблему ? Если дело в конфиге nginx, то, пожалуйста, напишите что и где прописать для правильной отдачи картинок

Comment: надо сделать так чтобы информация в БД была эквивалентна расположению файла на диске. всё прочее будет бесперспективным костылём.

Comment: На одном из серверов это работает, так что это не костыль, я понять не могу как это там настроено